# How to assign one chart to another C#

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm attempting to open a chart in another window form, however the classes used for the data in the chart is in the first form. My goal here is to have a chart be able to open many times in a modeless window.

in form1.cs I build my chart:

```
Chart chart = new Chart();
Series price = new Series("Price"); //create new series
chart.Series.Add(price);

chart.Series["Price"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Candlestick;

chart.Series["Price"]["OpenCloseStyle"] = "Candlestick";

chart.Series["Price"]["ShowOpenClose"] = "Both";


chart.Series["Price"]["PriceUpColor"] = "Green"; //Price increase = green
chart.Series["Price"]["PriceDownColor"] = "red"; //price decrease = red

for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    chart.Series["Price"].Points.AddXY(data[i].getDate(), data[i].getHigh()); //Adds date and high value
    chart.Series["Price"].Points[i].YValues[1] = System.Convert.ToDouble(data[i].getLow()); //Low value added to chart
    chart.Series["Price"].Points[i].YValues[2] = System.Convert.ToDouble(data[i].getOpen()); //open value added to chart
    chart.Series["Price"].Points[i].YValues[3] = System.Convert.ToDouble(data[i].getClose()); //close value added to chart
}
```

Form2.cs:

```
public void DisplayChart(Chart newChart)
{
   chart1 = newChart;
   chart1.Show();
}
```

Comment: Each window with same data? or different data using the same chart settings.

Comment: Same data. Same settings hopefully, I can change those latter if I have too.

Comment: what kind of context do use in your data variable?

Comment: My data variable is a list of candlesticks, which is a custom class I created. It only contains decimals open, high, low, close, and volume.

Comment: You need to get a public reference to the Chart and/ or its data source. There are about a million posts about referencing things from another form here!

Answer (score 0):

It is best to make the Chart is a separate class and call or create it from whichever form you need.
This follows object-oriented principles so you can reuse code and also use it for multiple purposes/views.

Comment: Chart is already a C# class, also I'm unable to use classes between forms for whatever reason. Otherwise I'd have my class with data[] in the second form and my problem would be solved because I could just use the data in that second form.